# Seaborn regplot with horizontal subplots with sharey=True and showing y tick labels

Tags: matplotlib, regression, seaborn

I have these three regplots side by side, however, I want to do these:
-increase the size of graphs
-separate them a little bit so can see the y axis more clearly
-see the values on y axis for the two right side graphs.

does anyone know how to do it efficiently? thanks

```
fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(ncols=3, sharey=True)
sns.regplot(x=Dem['Price'], y=Dem['A'], color="g", ax=ax1)
sns.regplot(x=Dem['Price'], y=Dem['B'], color="b", ax=ax2)
sns.regplot(x=Dem['Price'], y=Dem['C'], color="purple", ax=ax3)
```

[image]

Comment: If I have answered your question, then please accept it as solution by clicking the checkmark next to my solution. Please see the following link which shows you an image of how to do this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Thanks David. This was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can use: `fig.set_figwidth(25)` to widen the figure and create space passing whatever numeric value you desire, e.g. `25`.
2. To label the y-axis ticks of all subplots, use:

   ```
   for ax in fig.axes:
       ax.tick_params(axis='y', labelleft=True)
   ```

Full reproducible code sample with `flights` seaborn dataset:

```
import seaborn as sns
df = sns.load_dataset('flights')
df1 = df[df['year']==1949]
df2 = df[df['year']==1950]
df3 = df[df['year']==1951]
fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(ncols=3, sharey=True)

#1
fig.set_figwidth(25)

sns.regplot(x=df1['year'], y=df1['passengers'], color="g", ax=ax1)
sns.regplot(x=df2['year'], y=df2['passengers'], color="b", ax=ax2)
sns.regplot(x=df3['year'], y=df3['passengers'], color="purple", ax=ax3)

#2
for ax in fig.axes:
    ax.tick_params(axis='y', labelleft=True)
```

[image]

Your code:

```
fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(ncols=3, sharey=True)
fig.set_figwidth(25)
sns.regplot(x=Dem['Price'], y=Dem['A'], color="g", ax=ax1)
sns.regplot(x=Dem['Price'], y=Dem['B'], color="b", ax=ax2)
sns.regplot(x=Dem['Price'], y=Dem['C'], color="purple", ax=ax3)
for ax in fig.axes:
    ax.tick_params(axis='y', labelleft=True)
```